# Trouble with a RGBA generator

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, generator, rgba

I'm trying to make a RGBA generator. I used this code, but unfortunately it is for RGB, not RGBA I mean I don't know how to add an opacity property. So can you help me with this task? Here's the site, where i got the code: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker

```
<script>
function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
        r.toString(16),
        g.toString(16),
        b.toString(16)
    ];
    $.each(hex, function(nr, val) {
        if (val.length === 1) {
            hex[nr] = "0" + val;
        }
    });
    return hex.join("").toUpperCase();
}

function refreshSwatch() {
    var red = $("#red").slider("value"),
        green = $("#green").slider("value"),
        blue = $("#blue").slider("value"),
        hex = hexFromRGB(red, green, blue);
    $("#swatch").css("background-color", "#" + hex);
}
$(function() {
    $("#red, #green, #blue").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        max: 255,
        value: 127,
        slide: refreshSwatch,
        change: refreshSwatch
    });
    $("#red").slider("value", 255);
    $("#green").slider("value", 140);
    $("#blue").slider("value", 60);
});
</script>
```

Comment: A lot of different ways to do this; however, the best way might be to change the entire approach to this solution, and just use [rgba() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()). Another alternative is to use the [CSS opacity property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

Answer (score 0):

You should not recalculate the color. CSS can understood functions of colors `rgb()`, `rgba()`, `hsl()`:

```
$("#swatch").css("background-color", "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")");
```